# How to create Multiple root nodes in D3.js trees in same Svg

Tags: d3.js, svg

I need to create multiple root nodes (perhaps different root nodes/trees) in same svg. When there is no parent provided,the child itself should be created as root node (which leads to a separate Root node). So how can we create multiple root nodes (as single roots which has same properties as tree) in D3.js in same svg. 
I need any code snippet, as I am new to d3.js

Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: If somebody reply to this, its very helpful to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm new to D3 so maybe there's a solution more elegant than mine. It's really a trick:

In order to have *forests* instead of a single *tree*, you can create a fake root node, that is the parent of all the actual roots. Give it an attribute that allows you to discriminate, here for instance I added `fake: true` to its json.
And then simply hide it with CSS:

```
<style>
.fake {
  display: none;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
   // ...
   var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", function(d) {
        return d.fake ? "fake" : "node"
      })
   // etc.

   // Same on links:
   link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", function(d) {
        return d.source.fake ? "fake" : "link";
      })
   // etc.
</script>
```

Comment: Dear #Joel, i have one more question in stack overflow can u plz look into it...expecting any idea/any snippet for the same....Thanks in advance .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47870061/how-to-update-the-nodes-positions-in-d3-js-tree-after-having-some-operations-on